# schema.org is not working

Tags: php, schema

I tried implementing **schema.org** markup to display the star ratings, title, price, description etc when searched on google for a particular app or book or video. Unfortunately its not showing up. 
I have mentioned the bit of code which i used, kindly help me to fix the issue !!

```
<div vocab="http://schema.org" typeof="schema:Review">
<meta content="<?php echo$titl;?>" itemprop="name">
<meta content="<?php echo $img100; ?>" itemprop="image">

<div property="itemReviewed" typeof="schema:Thing" vocab="http://schema.org" >
<meta property="name" content="<?php echo $titl;?>" >  
</div>
<div property="author"  typeof="schema:Person" vocab="http://schema.org">
<meta property="name" content="App Store" >
</div>
<div property="reviewRating" typeof="schema:Rating" vocab="http://schema.org"  >
<meta property="ratingValue" content="<?php echo $rating;?>" >
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what do you see in generated html?

Comment: As mentioned by @u_mulder you should also provide the generated HTML. Filling your code with dummy values does not result in an error at the [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool). If the ratings are not showing up in the SERP: check if your site is following the [Review snippet guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews#review-snippet-guidelines)